# Proving a mod b < a/2 when a > b > 0

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

Suppose that $a \gt b \gt 0$.  How can one prove that $a$ mod $b \lt a/2$?

I understand why is that happening: if $a$ mod $b \gt a/2$ that means that $a/b \lt a/2$ and $a/b$ has enough "space" to get inside the $a$ mod $b$ one more time, since $a$ mod $b \gt a/2$.  This is a contradiction to the division result.

What is the formal proof for that? I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: I think you're missing a condition.  For instance $(2 \mod 3) = 2$ and this is not less than $\frac22$.

Comment: sorry , assuming that a>b

Comment: I'd consider three cases: $b<\frac{a}{2}$; $b>\frac{a}{2}$ and $b=\frac{a}{2}$.

Comment: I still have no direction where even start proving it..

Comment: You should begin with defining $a$ mod $b$ if you want a rigorous proof.  You seem to mean the remainder left when $a$ is divided by $b$ (both positive integers).  I've added the assumption that $a \gt b$ to your Question, per your Comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the facts that $(a \mod b)<b$ and that $(a\mod b)\le a-b$ (this second inequality holds in the case that $a\ge b$).

Comment: yes, I can see. I'll just sum the 2 equation and divide by 2. but how 2 get to these 2 equations?

Comment: ok I can see everything now . thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Let $a=bk+r$ with ($a$ mod $b$)$=r$.
We have to prove $r \lt a/2$ or we can change it to:

$$a-bk \lt a/2 \iff bk \gt a/2 \iff bk \gt  (bk+r)/2 \iff bk>r \quad \text{ (1) } $$

Because $r \lt b$, so (1) is correct. (QED)

Answer (score 0):

Let $a>b>0$ and write $a\bmod b=r$. This means $0\le r<b$ and $a=bq+r$ for some $q>0$. Suppose $r>a/2$; then you have
$$
a<2r<2b
$$
that can be written
$$
a<2a-2bq<2b
$$
because $r=a-bq$.
This in turn gives
$$
\begin{cases}
a>2bq\\
a<b(q+1)
\end{cases}
$$
What condition on $q$ can you derive?